# Is it possible to enable DHCP server on wlan interface during startup?

Tags: wireless, dhcp, hot-spot

To change a box to unattended AP, DHCP service need to be bound to the wlan interface during the system startup.

But there is few article to mention how to assign a static IP to the wireless card during the startup, although manually assignment is workable after the start-up.

Netplan or NetworkManager can do it for me. But got some issue with these 2 and turn to hostapd+dnsmasq now.

As per my understanding, as tons of wifi router has similar requirement, it should be also workable on an Ubuntu box, shouldn't it?

Please share you wisdom on how to bind a DHCP server to a wireless interface automatically after the server boot.